# New to SQL Injections (error)

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-injection

I've been advised to use anti-sql injection methods, as I am inserting values inside my database. I've looked around the web, and my first failed attempt is this, of which I need some help, with the PDO method. I found examples online to be waaay too empty of substance for me to understand (btw, I ran a line and it told me PDO is enabled):

Is this good in any way, shape or form?

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
// Host, User, Pass, DB
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","*****","*****","*****");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQLi: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = '****';
$user = '****';
$pass = '*****';

try {
  # MS SQL Server and Sybase with PDO_DBLIB
  $DBH = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname, $user, $pass");
  $DBH = new PDO("sybase:host=$host;dbname=$dbname, $user, $pass");

  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

  # SQLite Database
  $DBH = new PDO("sqlite:my/database/path/database.db");
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also, I get this error upon submitting my form:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/product/*****/*****/*****/processForm-test.php on line 68
```

Comment: you can not mix and match Mysqli and PDO. Use either one of them but not both.

Comment: Your code does not contain any call to a `prepare()` method.

Comment: Your code is basically useless for answering your question, as you don't show how you actually RUN the queries. In a real world equivalent, you're asking if having fuzzy dice on your car's rearview mirror will make you a good driver.

Comment: MySQli it will be then... feel comfortable at this point with it. I will search for that then. Thank you.

Comment: @ Marc B. I wasn't even there yet in my code.

Comment: if you haven't gone too far with mysqli yet, i would **strongly** suggest switching to pdo. it's more portable and has more features, while mysqli is more limited, (arguably) harder to work with, and only works with php. for almost any project, there is absolutely NO good reason to use mysqli over pdo.

Comment: My whole code is centered around mysqli. But, I am trying to secure it though - this is what I meant when I said I wasn't that far in the coding.

Comment: ohhh. in that case, definitely DON'T switch (not worth your time!). just start using prepared statements if you're not already (google "mysqli prepared statements"; there's tons of examples). that's all you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One big problem in your code is that it's using both `mysqli_connect` and `PDO` to create database connections. Don't do that; that's not supported. Use one or the other.

The lines you have that make PDO connections attempt to connect to four separate databases, SQL Server, Sybase, MySQL and SQLLite, all running on localhost. But you are keeping a handle to only the last one, since you're assigning the database connection to the same variable.

That variable `$DBH` is your reference to the database session (connection), if the connect succeeds. If it doesn't succeed, that gets assigned a value of `false`, which you can test, before you proceed.

I think all you need is a single PDO connection to MySQL, like this:

```
<?php
include ('config.php');

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = '****';
$user = '****';
$pass = '*****';
try {
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connect failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

I'm extrapolating here, but the most likely explanation for the error message you are getting is that you've got a line of code (not shown in your code sample) like this:

```
$sth = $DBH->prepare($sql);
```

The issue is that `$DBH` is not a reference to valid database connection. `$DBH` has a value of 'false', and that's because the attempt to connect to the database failed. And `false` is not an object, so there's no way it can have a method named 'prepare' associated with it.